# AWK Include Whitespaces in Command

Tags: unix, awk, command, solaris

I have  String:  "./Delivery Note.doc 1"  ,  where:

```
$1 = ./Delivery
$2 = Note.doc
$3 = 1
```

I need to execute sum command concatenating $1 and $2 but keeping white space (./Delivery Note.doc). I try this but it trim whitespaces:

```
| '{ command="sum -r "$1 $2"
```

Result: ./DeliveryNote.doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the sum command

```
echo  "./Delivery Note.doc 1" | awk '{ command="sum -r \""$1" "$2"\""; print command}' | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo  "./Delivery Note.doc 1" | awk '{ command="sum -r "$1" "$2; print command}'
sum -r ./Delivery Note.doc
```